# SQL 2012 - SSIS Package not populating Text file when scheduled

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-2012, agent

I'm working on SQL 2012 Enterprise and I have a set of SSIS package exports which push data out to text files on a shared network folder. The packages aren't complex and under most circumstances they work perfectly. The problem I'm facing is that they do not work when scheduled - despite reporting that they have succeded.

Let me explain the scenarios;
1) When run manually from within BIDS, they work correctly, txt files are created and populated with data.
2) When deployed to the SSISDB and run from the Agent job they also work as expected - files are created and populate with data.
3) When the Agent job is scheduled to run in the evening, the job runs and reports success. The files are created but the data is not populated.

I've checked the reports on the Integration Services Catalogs and compared the messages line by line from the OnInformation. Both runs reports that the Flat File Destination wrote xxxx rows.

The data is there, the Agent account has the correct access. I cannot fathom why the job works when started manually, but behaves differently when scheduled.

Has anyone seen anything similar? It feels like a very strange bug....

Kind Regards,

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the account you have set up as the proxy for the SSIS task has read/write access to the file.

IMX, when you run an SQL Agent job manually, it appears to use the context of the user who initiates it in some way.  I always assumed it was a side effect of impersonation.  It's only when it actually runs with the schedule that everything uses the assigned security rights.

Additionally, I think when the user starts the job, the user is impersonating the proxy, but when the job is run via the schedule, the agent's account is impersonating the proxy.  Make sure the service account has the right to impersonate the proxy.  Take a look at `sp_grant_login_to_proxy` and `sp_enum_login_for_proxy`.

Here's a link that roughly goes through the process:
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2163/running-a-ssis-package-from-sql-server-agent-using-a-proxy-account/

I also recall this video being useful:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd440761(v=SQL.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd440761%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately that's not it though. My first thought was permissions but the agent is using the same service account which we've always used and has privileges to the destination. I've also checked the job history and it's using the service account to execute the package even if it's invoked by the user account.  I also tried another test yesterday - scheduling the job on a "Run Once" type schedule for a set time during the day. Amazingly, this also worked fine, but the issue re-occured again last night when executed by the recurring schedule.

Comment: OK, this wasn't the reason - I was being a fool. I hadn't disabled the previous jobs on the old server, so they were running correctly the whole time, but being overwritten by the jobs on the old server.  I can't believe my first post was st00pid!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Excel files. It was permission rights.

What worked for me was adding the `SERVICE` account to the folder's security tab. Then the SQL Agent can access the files.

[image: Folder security]